# How to get a ActiveRecord count working with select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following situation:

I have a select query where i have to calculate a value within the select. When I then call `any?` or `count` it results in a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Expection:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(foos.*, (foos.bar+1) as calculated) FROM "foos`

I've setup this in a small test that looks like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'any on active record relation' do
    foos = Foo.select('foos.*, (foos.bar+1) as calculated')
    assert(foos.any?, 'expected to work')
  end
end
```

It seems to be an issue of rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15138
So my first idea was to just load the results using `all` but that doesn't affect anything.

Btw. I am using Rails 4.1

Any Ideas how to work around this?

Edit:

The reason why I want to do this is the folllowing:

I have an Model that contains a long/lat location. WHen I query the the model, I calculate the distance to a given location and order the records by distance. so my query looks something like this:

```
nearest_records = MyModel
        .select("mymodels.*, 
             ST_Distance(mymodels.lnglat, #{user_location}) as distance")
        .order(distance).limit(6)
```

This works perfectly. But now in my view I want to know if my list contains any records so i call `any?`. And this breaks the hole thing as described. Its caused by the said bug as `any?` uses count.

So my first try was just to execute the query by using the `all` method but that doesn't seam to work. My current workaround is to trigger the query by calling `each` on the ActiveRecordRelation and then break at the first element.

```
nearest_records.each { break }
```

But I really don't like this soloution. Hope someone can help me with this.

I am using Rails 4.1.0

Comment: I have problem with the count. For me any? seems to working. which version of rails you using? i am using 4.1.8.

Comment: @Saravanan thanks for this hint. I updated rails to version 4.1.8 and it works now. It seems they have fixed the any? issue. When you use count, just provide a param to count, for example, :all `Foo.select('foos.*, (foos.bar+1) as calculated').count(:all)` works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different issue to the one you have linked, I would not really consider it an issue with Rails, as it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

The `any?` method performs a count of records matching certain criteria and returns true if the count is non zero. Combining this query with a select as above makes no sense, there are no conditions provided.

Providing arguments to select only works if you want to retrieve a subset of columns from the table, (or columns from another table perhaps). When you want to count a number of records, you only need to select `COUNT(id)` or similiar, but Rails does this automatically.

If you could explain a bit more about what your code is supposed to do it might help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `any?` Rails wraps sql select statement in `COUNT`. 
Using `select` with `any?` results in a wrong SQL statement, because you can not use several columns within `COUNT`.

Moreover, counting several columns only makes sense with aggregating functions or `DISTINCT`.
For example,

```rb
# count all records and count distinct 'bar' 
Foo.select('count(*), count(distinct(bar))')
# count all records and sum 'bar'
Foo.select('count(*), sum(bar)')
```